# ggplot2 plot without axes, legends, etc

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to use bioconductor's hexbin (which I can do) to generate a plot that fills the entire (png) display region - no axes, no labels, no background, no nuthin'.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to create a hexbin plot and the crop it in an image editor?

Comment: try `theme_void()`

Answer (score 227):

As per my comment in Chase's answer, you can remove a lot of this stuff using `element_blank`:

```
dat <- data.frame(x=runif(10),y=runif(10))

p <- ggplot(dat, aes(x=x, y=y)) + 
        geom_point() +
        scale_x_continuous(expand=c(0,0)) + 
        scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0,0))   

p + theme(axis.line=element_blank(),axis.text.x=element_blank(),
          axis.text.y=element_blank(),axis.ticks=element_blank(),
          axis.title.x=element_blank(),
          axis.title.y=element_blank(),legend.position="none",
          panel.background=element_blank(),panel.border=element_blank(),panel.grid.major=element_blank(),
          panel.grid.minor=element_blank(),plot.background=element_blank())
```

It looks like there's still a small margin around the edge of the resulting .png when I save this. Perhaps someone else knows how to remove even that component.

(Historical note: Since **ggplot2** version 0.9.2, `opts` has been deprecated. Instead use `theme()` and replace `theme_blank()` with `element_blank()`.)

Comment: Many thanks! I also found a similar solution at http://groups.google.com/group/ggplot2/browse_thread/thread/72403c6997b79c3b

Comment: Comment in passing: In some cases, ``theme(axis.ticks=element_blank())`` does not work as well as ``theme(axis.ticks.x=element_blank())``, probably a temporary bug somewhere (I have my own theme set, then I attempt to override: only ``axis.ticks.x`` and ``axis.ticks.y`` do the job.)

Comment: I was able to get rid of the extra margin with:
`theme(plot.margin=grid::unit(c(0,0,0,0), "mm"))`

Answer (score 122):

Re: changing opts to theme etc (for lazy folks):

```
theme(axis.line=element_blank(),
      axis.text.x=element_blank(),
      axis.text.y=element_blank(),
      axis.ticks=element_blank(),
      axis.title.x=element_blank(),
      axis.title.y=element_blank(),
      legend.position="none",
      panel.background=element_blank(),
      panel.border=element_blank(),
      panel.grid.major=element_blank(),
      panel.grid.minor=element_blank(),
      plot.background=element_blank())
```

Comment: Although `theme_void` offered in another answer is the easiest way to achieve the OP's aims, if combining with `facet_grid` or `facet_wrap` you will also lose the boxes around the facet labels. If you don't want this to happen, this answer is the one to use.

Answer (score 88):

Current answers are either incomplete or inefficient. Here is (perhaps) the shortest way to achieve the outcome (using `theme_void()`):

```r
data(diamonds) # Data example

ggplot(data = diamonds, mapping = aes(x = clarity)) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill = cut)) +
  theme_void() +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

The outcome is:

[image]

---

If you are interested in just eliminating the **labels**, `labs(x="", y="")` does the trick:

```r
ggplot(data = diamonds, mapping = aes(x = clarity)) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill = cut)) + 
  labs(x = "", y = "")
```

Comment: `ggplot(data = diamonds, mapping = aes(x = clarity)) + geom_bar(aes(fill = cut)) +
  theme_void() + 
  theme(legend.position="none", 
        panel.background = element_rect(fill="grey80"), 
        plot.background = element_rect(fill="red"))` suggests it's not 100% void

Comment: The labs( x="", y="" ) does not appear to remove the axes, just the labels.

Comment: @miratrix sorry, my mistake. Updated.

Comment: @luchonacho Using `labs(x="",y="")` leaves space of axis titles because actually there are titles, they are just without signs. To remove axis titles and space for them it is better to use `+ theme(axis.title = element_blank())`

Comment: ``labs(x = NULL)`` or ``xlab(NULL)`` are other ways.

Answer (score 43):

```
'opts' is deprecated.
```

in `ggplot2 >= 0.9.2` use

```
p + theme(legend.position = "none")
```

Comment: I realize you don't have edit privileges yet, but if you spot other ggplot2 answers of mine that need to be updated re:opts() feel free to suggest an edit. I'll get a notification and can incorporate it myself.

Answer (score 13):

*Late to the party, but might be of interest...*

I find a combination of `labs` and `guides` specification useful in many cases:

You want nothing but a grid and a background:

```
ggplot(diamonds, mapping = aes(x = clarity)) + 
  geom_bar(aes(fill = cut)) + 
  labs(x = NULL, y = NULL) + 
  guides(x = "none", y = "none")
```

[image]

You want to only suppress the tick-mark label of one or both axes:

```
ggplot(diamonds, mapping = aes(x = clarity)) + 
  geom_bar(aes(fill = cut)) + 
  guides(x = "none", y = "none")
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
xy <- data.frame(x=1:10, y=10:1)
plot <- ggplot(data = xy)+geom_point(aes(x = x, y = y))
plot
panel = grid.get("panel-3-3")

grid.newpage()
pushViewport(viewport(w=1, h=1, name="layout"))
pushViewport(viewport(w=1, h=1, name="panel-3-3"))
upViewport(1)
upViewport(1)
grid.draw(panel)
```

Comment: `Error in UseMethod("grid.draw") : 
  no applicable method for 'grid.draw' applied to an object of class "NULL"`

Comment: grid.ls() display the list of viewport and grob objects

Comment: it appears that in other version of ggplot that i am using the panel name is different

Comment: xy <- data.frame(x=1:10, y=10:1)
plot <- ggplot(data = xy)+geom_point(aes(x = x, y = y))
plot
panel = grid.get("panel-3-4")

grid.newpage()
pushViewport(viewport(w=1, h=1, name="layout"))
pushViewport(viewport(w=1, h=1, name="panel-3-4"))
upViewport(1)
upViewport(1)
grid.draw(panel)

Answer (score 3):

use ggeasy, it is more simple.

```
library(ggeasy)
p + theme_classic()+easy_remove_axes() + easy_remove_legend()
```

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find this solution here. It removes all of it using the cowplot package:

```
library(cowplot)

p + theme_nothing() +
theme(legend.position="none") +
scale_x_continuous(expand=c(0,0)) +
scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0,0)) +
labs(x = NULL, y = NULL)
```

Just noticed that the same thing can be accomplished using theme.void() like this:

```
p + theme_void() +
theme(legend.position="none") +
scale_x_continuous(expand=c(0,0)) +
scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0,0)) +
labs(x = NULL, y = NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you want?

```
 p <- ggplot(myData, aes(foo, bar)) + geom_whateverGeomYouWant(more = options) +
 p + scale_x_continuous(expand=c(0,0)) + 
 scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0,0)) +
 opts(legend.position = "none")
```

Comment: gets rid of legend but x and y axes, and the background grid, are still there.