# ggplot graph with no y variable

Tags: r, ggplot2

How do I use ggplot to create a number line-type graph where the points are different colors and sizes to represent different variables? I tried this:

```
ggplot(data=data, aes(x=x, fill=fill, size=size)) + geom_point()
```

But I get the following error:

```
Error in as.environment(where) : 'where' is missing
```

I have no idea what that means. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: geom_point is used to create scatterplots, when you have 2 variables. I am not sure what you are trying to do.  Can you give an example ?

Comment: I'm also unsure what you're trying to do given the description. How can you have a point without it being two dimensional - with an x position and a y position?
Perhaps try qplot and see if the default aesthetic is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

There are two main steps: create a dummy variable for y and remove the y axis as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6542792).

```
library(tidyverse)

mtcars %>%
  rownames_to_column() %>%
  # Dummy variable
  add_column(y = 0) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = mpg, y = y, label = rowname)) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_text(hjust = 'left', angle = 80, size = 2) +
  # Make sure line is on the bottom
  ylim(0, 0.1) +
  # Remove axis lines and everything on y-axis
  theme_classic() +
  theme(axis.title.y =element_blank(),
    axis.text.y = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks.y=element_blank(),
    axis.line = element_blank()) +
  # Add number line
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0) +
  labs(title = 'Ranking by MPG')
```

After that, it's working with your figure height and width to make sure there isn't excess white space.