# Not sure why this subset is not working in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, subset

I have sub-setted my data set so that only three sites are included, as I only want to plot three sites and the following code does not seem to work with ggplot. Anyone have any idea why?

```
rm(list=ls())
require(ggplot2)
require(reshape2)
require(magrittr)
require(dplyr)
require(tidyr)
setwd("~/Documents/Results")
mydata <- read.csv("Metals sheet R.csv")
L <- subset(mydata, Site =="B1"| Site == "B2"| Site == "B3", select =       c(Site,Date,Al))
L$Date <- as.Date(L$Date, "%d/%m/%Y")
ggplot(data=L, aes(x=Date, y=Al, xaxt="n", colour=Site)) +
geom_point() + 
labs(title = "Total Al in the Barlwyd and Bowydd
   19/03/2015.", x = "Site",
   y = "Total concentration (mg/L)") +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 month", labels = date_format("%m"))
```

It seems to falter after the ggplot line. Thanks in advance. I have double checked it but can't see anything wrong? I might possibly need a way to only plot three of my 21 sites.

The head of my subsetted L data set looks something  like this (x58 reps)

```
Date          Site        Al
12/08/2015    B1         22.3
12/08/2015    B2         23.4
12/08/2015    B3         203
```

Thankyou in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `xaxt = "n"` is wrong. The ggplot `aes` function is only for matching variables in your data to plot elements. To remove the x-axis text in ggplot, use the `theme` function e.g. [ggplot2 plot without axes, legends, etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6528180/ggplot2-plot-without-axes-legends-etc).

On a separate note, the `%in%` operator provides a quicker way of selecting a subset of values from a column:

`subset(mydata, Site %in% c("B1", "B2", B3"))`