# r - ggplot paired seq

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, dplyr

I am having trouble plotting `paired` data with `ggplot2`.

So, I have a database with paired (`idpair`) individuals (`id`) and their respective sequences, such as

```
   idpair id 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
1       1  1 d b d a c a d d a  b
2       1  2 e d a c c d a b a  c
3       2  3 e a a a a c d b c  e
4       2  4 d d b c d e a a a  b 
...
```

What I would like is to plot all the sequences but that somewhat we can visually distinguish the pair.

I thought of using the grid such as: `facet_grid(idpair~.)`. My issue looks like this:

[image]

How could I plot the two sequences side by side removing the "vacuum" in between caused by the other `idpair` ?

Any suggestions of alternative plotting of paired data are very welcome.

**My code**

```
library(ggplot2) 
library(dplyr) 
library(reshape2) 

dtmelt = dt %>% melt(id.vars = c('idpair', 'id')) %>% arrange(idpair, id, variable)

dtmelt %>% ggplot(aes(y = id, x = variable, fill = value)) + 
  geom_tile() + scale_fill_brewer(palette = 'Set3') + 
  facet_grid(idpair~.) + theme(legend.position = "none")
```

**generate the data**

```
dt = as.data.frame( cbind( sort( rep(1:10, 2) ) , 1:20, replicate(10, sample(letters[1:5], 20, replace = T)) ) ) 
colnames(dt) = c('idpair', 'id', 1:10)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove the unused levels in the facet by setting `scales = "free_y"`. This will vary the y-axis limits for each facet.

```
dtmelt %>% ggplot(aes(y = id, x = variable, fill = value)) + 
    geom_tile() + scale_fill_brewer(palette = 'Set3') + 
    facet_grid(idpair~., scales = "free_y") + theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image]

Comment: is there any possibility just to keep the labels on the right (`idpair`) and remove the ones on the left ? Also how can I control the grid space between groups ? (thanks for sorry for the additional questions)

Comment: @giacomoV check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6528180/ggplot2-plot-without-axes-legends-etc