# How to plot heatmap using 2 matrix in r

Tags: r, matrix, ggplot2

I am trying to create a heatmap, but am confused as to how to. Here are the dataframes.

```
Ticker <- c("S&P 500","Dow Jones Index","AAPL","MSFT","FB","NFLX","GOOG","JPM","TSLA")
Values <- c(2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1)

ticker_matrix <- matrix(Ticker , nrow = 3, ncol = 3)
values_matrix <- matrix(Values, nrow = 3, ncol = 3)
```

How should i use ggplot2 to plot a heat map that looks like this?

[image]

the matrix plot is a 3x3 matrix whereby positive numbers are in green (the larger the number, the darker the green), and negative number in red, it will be even better.

Edit:

Thanks Camille for highlighting the broadness of the question, i shall narrow down the question further by making reference to d.b's answer.

d.b's answer is in the exact direction i am seeking. whereby the heatmap is shown in a 3x3 matrix based on the scale of underlying value in the background. 
(the purpose of this visualization is to show how positive or negative a particular stock's sentiment is)

Building on d.b's answer (whereby values are colored in discrete factors), i will post an alternative solution with continuous variables on the scale. Thanks all!

Comment: Does`heatmap.2` from `gplots` help?

Comment: There are enough ways, and without seeing what you've tried so far, I'd consider this borderline too broad a question. A bunch of examples are in the R Graph Gallery: https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/heatmap/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
d = data.frame(Ticker = as.vector(ticker_matrix),
               Values = as.vector(values_matrix),
               X = as.vector(row(ticker_matrix)),
               Y = as.vector(col(ticker_matrix)))

ggplot(data = d,
       mapping = aes(x = factor(X),
                     y = factor(Y),
                     fill = factor(Values),
                     label = Ticker)) +
    geom_tile(color = "white") +
    geom_text() +
    coord_equal()
```

[image]

If you want to remove axes and legends, check out the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6528180/7128934).

Answer (score 1):

continuous variable version (range from c(-1,2)) of d.b's answer:

```
d = data.frame(Ticker = as.vector(ticker_matrix),
           Values = as.numeric(values_matrix),
           X = as.vector(row(ticker_matrix)),
           Y = as.vector(col(ticker_matrix)))

ggplot(data = d,
   mapping = aes(x = factor(X),
                 y = factor(Y),
                 fill = Values,
                 label = Ticker)) +
    geom_tile() +
    geom_text() +
    coord_equal() + 
    scale_fill_gradientn(colors = c("dark red", "red3", "white", "green3", "dark green"),
      limits=c(-1, 2))
```

[image]