# Get rid of the data labels on a x axis in a R ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to fix my Plot(GGplot) in R to remove the overlapping text from the graph since there is a Key on the side that explains it better.

```
spending_clean %>%
mutate(totalfunding =total_funding_amount/500000000) %>%
  group_by(awarding_agency_name) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=awarding_agency_name, y = totalfunding,color=awarding_agency_name))+
     geom_boxplot(position = position_dodge(50000000))
```

[image: Results of my attempt]

My question. How do I get rid of the overlapping text/hide the text?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6528180/1315767

Comment: This sounds like a good use case to switch your axes and put the agency name on y and the funding amount on x. That way the labels can be aligned with their values, much easier than making the reader match along a color scale.